# Tuleap - SVN url not found on the server

Tags: mysql, svn, tuleap

I'm using the latest version of Tuleap. Last month I kept one project status as holding, because I didn't want the project to be seen in the admin dashboard.
Last evening I activated the project for my team, so they can create tasks etc, but I couldn't able to checkout the svn files in the repository.
When I tried to checkout it is showing `The requested URL /svnroot/liferay was not found on this server`, but I am able to browse & view the files through the Tuleap tool.
The projects which are currently active, I am able to checkout & commit the files.

Get me out of this error, since all my updated files are in that repository.

Answer (score 0):

Actually "Holding" purges the data (it's an alias for Deleted).

Basically your project is gone

Comment: Is there a way to activate the svnroot repository

Comment: Not really. You might hack in the DB to get the link back but your project would be in a so weird state that's really un-advised.